# Erro ao customizar o InfoWindowAdapter no Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Tenho este arquivo XML:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_carro"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mmarker_snippet"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/marker_titulo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/mmarker_snippet"
        android:layout_below="@+id/marker_titulo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/marker_titulo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/marker_titulo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

E o código para:

```
mapa.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                    if (janela == null) {

                        janela = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);

                        janela.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                        TextView markerTitulo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marker_titulo);
                        markerTitulo.setText(marker.getTitle());

                        TextView markerSnippet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mmarker_snippet);
                        markerSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());


                    }

                    return janela;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

                    return null;
                }

            });
```

NB: `janela` refer-se à uma `View` que declarei na mesma classe.

Mas quando executo a app, sempre que clico no marcador, recebo um NullPointerException e não entendo porquê.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) que está a chamar é do objecto Activity.
Ele encontra *views* que estejam no layout passado ao método [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)).

No código postado as views `markerTitulo` e `markerSnippet` encontram-se na view `janela`, que foi criada na linha

```
janela = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
```

Para obter a referência a essas views deve usar o método [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) do objecto `janela`, que é do tipo View.

em vez de

```
TextView markerTitulo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marker_titulo);
markerTitulo.setText(marker.getTitle());

TextView markerSnippet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mmarker_snippet);
markerSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
```

use

```
TextView markerTitulo = (TextView) janela.findViewById(R.id.marker_titulo);
markerTitulo.setText(marker.getTitle());

TextView markerSnippet = (TextView) janela.findViewById(R.id.mmarker_snippet);
markerSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
```